# Getting desired values from data frame R

Tags: r

I have a problem with getting data from data frame. My data frame has two fields: time (currently it is 1:10) and values for each position. I'm using S3 model. I created function which takes condition (as a String) and then should return data according to that condition. After that I get no data.

What's more could anyone tell me how to write another function the way that I get particular data using following expression: "object = sts[1:5]" How to write such function?

```
sts <- function(timeRange = NULL, valuesForTimeRange = NULL)
{

  me <- data.frame(
    timeRangeFrame = timeRange,
    valuesForEachTime = valuesForTimeRange
  )

  ## Set the name for the class
  class(me) <- append(class(me),"sts")
  return(me)
}

selectMethodWithCondition <- function(objecto, condition)
{
  print("Calling the base selectMethodWithCondition function")
  UseMethod("selectMethodWithCondition",objecto)

}

selectMethodWithCondition.sts <- function(objecto, condition)
{
  print("In selectMethodWithCondition.STS")


  dataFrameToReturn = subset(objecto, eval(condition))

  return(dataFrameToReturn)

}

    stsObiekt = sts(timeRange = c(1:10),valuesForTimeRange = c(1:10))
stsObiekt
class(stsObiekt)

ss <- expression(valuesForEachTime == ",valuesForEachTime > 5 & valuesForEachTime < 10")

dataCondition = selectMethodWithCondition(objecto = stsObiekt,condition = ss)
dataCondition
## Here I get no data
```

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Comment: I have review and updated comment.

Comment: The inputs are missing.

Comment: Hope it is now clear.